# tzwhere (pytzwhere) - Python 2.7 with simple test case

Tags: python, ipython, pytz

I'm running the simplest possible test problem that is given with the pytzwhere package.  The module imports, but I'm getting an error.  pytzwhere seems like a good offline option for getting timezones from GPS coordinates, but there isn't much documentation. Any help on how to reconcile this is appreciated!

```
In [94]:

import tzwhere

w = tzwhere()
print w.tzNameAt(1.352083, 103.819836)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-0b50c8083e93> in <module>()
      1 import tzwhere
      2 
----> 3 w = tzwhere()
      4 print w.tzNameAt(1.352083, 103.819836)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

### Edit:

This has been resolved with the following code modification per the comments below -

```
In [108]:

from tzwhere import tzwhere

w = tzwhere.tzwhere()
print w.tzNameAt(1.352083, 103.819836)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reading json input file: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tzwhere/tz_world_compact.json
Asia/Singapore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just instantiave w from module like `w = tzwhere()`. tzwhere is a module containing class tzwhere. As Python correctly noted, module is not callable.

`from tzwhere import tzwhere
w = tzwhere()`

First line imports **class** tzwhere from **module** tzwhere.

Edit: If you do import "my way" :-)  `w = tzwhere()` is valid creation of w as instance of **class** tzwhere.

Usually in Python, class would be named TzWhere, which would avoid such confusion.

I assume you are trying to use https://github.com/pegler/pytzwhere/blob/master/tzwhere/tzwhere.py

Comment: Yes, this is the package that I'm trying to use.  I tried w=tzwhere.tzwhere(), which I thought would work with a simple import tzwhere.  Now with both 'from tzwhere import tzwhere' and 'w=tzwhere.tzwhere()' it works.  Thanks for your help.